# List of names and their numbers needed to be sorted .TXT file

Tags: sorting, text, numbers, text-files

I have a list of names (never over 100 names) with a value for each of them, either 3 or 4 digits.

> john2E=1023
>   mary2E=1045
>   fred2E=968

And so on... They're formatted exactly like that in the .txt file. I have Python and Excel, also willing to download whatever I need.

**What I want to do is** sort all the names according to their values in a descending order so highest is on top. I've tried to use Excel by replacing the '2E=' with ',' so I can have the name,value then important the data so each are in separate columns but I still couldn't sort them any other way than A to Z.

Help is much appreciated, I did take my time to look around before posting this.

Comment: right click on the header of the value column, select "Format Cells" from context menu. Then, From Number tab, select Number. Click OK to save. Then try sorting by that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the "2E=" with a tab character so that the data is displayed in excel in two columns.  Then sort on the value column.

Comment: Thank you, that worked. I had to copy and paste instead of importing data but that doesn't matter.

Comment: Or precondition (substitute 2E= by some whitespace) it with a text editor in case excel can't do it.